# Using Pytest to monkeypatch an initialized redis connection in a flask application

Tags: python, flask, redis, pytest

I've been struggling with this for awhile now. I Have a flask app that is executed in my app.py file. In this file I have a bunch of endpoints that call different functions from other files. In another file, extensions.py, I've instantiated a class that contains a redis connection. See the file structure below.

```
#app.py

from flask import Flask

from extensions import redis_obj

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/flush-cache', methods=['POST'])
def flush_redis():
    result = redis_obj.flush_redis_cache()
    return result

# extensions.py
from redis_class import CloudRedis

redis_obj = CloudRedis()

# redis_class
import redis

class CloudRedis:

    def __init__(self):
 
            self.conn = redis.Redis(connection_pool=redis.ConnectionPool.from_url('REDIS_URL',
                        ssl_cert_reqs=None))

    def flush_redis_cache(self):
 
        try:
            self.conn.flushdb()
            return 'OK'
        except:
            return 'redis flush failed'
```

I've been attempting to use monkeypatching in a test patch flush_redis_cache, so when I run flush_redis() the call to redis_obj.flush_redis_cache() will just return "Ok", since I've already tested the CloudRedis class in other pytests. However, no matter what I've tried I haven't been able to successfully patch this. This is what I have below.

```
from extensions import redis_obj
from app import app
@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    yield app.test_client()

def test_flush_redis_when_redis_flushed(client, monkeypatch):

    # setup
    def get_mock_flush_redis_cache():
        return 'OK'

    monkeypatch.setattr(cloud_reids, 'flush_redis_cache', get_mock_flush_redis_cache)
    cloud_redis.flush_redis = get_mock_flush_redis_cache
    # act
    res = client.post('/flush-cache')
    result = flush_redis()
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: You may want to try fakeredis
https://pypi.org/project/fakeredis/

Comment: I've used fakeredis to mock the redis connection in other pytests, what I want to do here is just patch a class function of an object that has already been instantiated